# What is the way of permanently changing class variables from inside the member function?

Tags: python, class, init, member-functions

```
print("Hello World")
class testing:

  params = 1
  print(params)

  #@classmethod
  def __init__(self, params):
    self.params = params

  print(params)
b = testing(params = 5)
```

Output:

```
Hello World 
1
1
```

How do I get changed values of params using `__init__` or any other function while keeping params as class variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? The `__init__` method directly changes the class variable.

```
print("Hello World")


class testing:
    params = 1
    print(params)

    # @classmethod
    def __init__(self, params):
        # self.params = params
        testing.params = params


b = testing(params=5)
print(testing.params)
```

Comment: @runaway57 Nice. Would you select this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you assign it. `self.params` is a class-level variable, meaning you can manipulate and call it using `self.params`. In the lines of code:

```
params = 1
print(params)
```

`params` is a different variable than `self.params`, defined later. To print that, you would write:

```
print(self.params)
```

somewhere after your `__init__()` function wherein it was defined.